# Openpyxl, how to do two operations on x-axis labels, rotating and change font, without one overrides the other

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I aim to rotate the labels on the x-axis and change font. However, in the code below, these two operations work individually, but when I do both, the rotating is undone by the font change.

How can I do these two operations on my chart?

```
import openpyxl
from openpyxl.chart import BarChart, Reference
from openpyxl.chart.text import RichText
from openpyxl.drawing.text import Paragraph, ParagraphProperties, CharacterProperties, Font as Font2

# Create a workbook and activate a sheet
wb = openpyxl.Workbook()
sheet = wb.active

# insert some categories
cell = sheet.cell(row=1, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 1.1' 
cell = sheet.cell(row=2, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 1.2 - limit'
cell = sheet.cell(row=3, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 2'
cell = sheet.cell(row=4, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 2.1 - extra'
cell = sheet.cell(row=5, column=1)
cell.value = 'Category 2.2 - extra2'

# insert some values
for i in range(5):
    cell = sheet.cell(row=i+1, column=2)
    cell.value = i+2

# create chart
chart = BarChart()

values = Reference(sheet, min_col = 2, min_row = 1,
                         max_col = 2, max_row = 5)

bar_categories = Reference(sheet, min_col=1, min_row=1, max_row=5)
chart.add_data(values)
chart.set_categories(bar_categories)

chart.title = " BAR-CHART "
chart.legend = None
chart.x_axis.title = " X_AXIS "
chart.y_axis.title = " Y_AXIS "

 # Rotate X-axis labels, operation 1
chart.x_axis.txPr = chart.x_axis.title.text.rich
chart.x_axis.txPr.properties.rot = "-2700000"
chart.x_axis.title = None

# Adjust font, operation 2, 
font_ = Font2(typeface='Avenir Next LT Pro')
cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font_, sz=900)
chart.x_axis.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])

sheet.add_chart(chart, "E2")
 
# save the file
wb.save("barChart.xlsx")
```

Comment: You're overwriting the axis `txPr` object when you assign the `CharacterProperties`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Re-arranging the last lines of your code like this works;

```
### Adjust font, operation 2,
font_ = Font2(typeface='Avenir Next LT Pro')
cp = CharacterProperties(latin=font_, sz=900)

### Rotate X-axis labels, operation 1
# chart.x_axis.txPr = chart.x_axis.title.text.rich

chart.x_axis.txPr = RichText(p=[Paragraph(pPr=ParagraphProperties(defRPr=cp), endParaRPr=cp)])
chart.x_axis.txPr.properties.rot = "-2700000"

chart.x_axis.title = None

sheet.add_chart(chart, "E2")

### save the file
wb.save("barChart.xlsx")
```

[image]

Comment: okey, I wonder why? Order of operations is of course important, but still, I dont get the logic here.

Comment: Actually the line `chart.x_axis.txPr = chart.x_axis.title.text.rich` does nothing and can be removed so it's just in the order the font and rotation are applied it seems.